# Spark Dataset Error: Both sides of this join are outside the broadcasting threshold and computing it could be prohibitively expensive

Tags: sql, performance, apache-spark, dataframe, dataset

I am using Spark2.0.2 in local mode. I have a join which join two datasets.

It is quite fast when using spark sql or dataframe API (untyped Dataset[Row] ).
But when I use typed Dataset API, I get the error below.

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Both sides of this join are outside the broadcasting threshold and computing it could be prohibitively expensive. To explicitly enable it, please set spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled = true;

I increase "spark.sql.conf.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", but it is still the same error. And then I set "spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled" to "true", it works but takes very long time to complete.

I didn't do any repartition. The source are two parquets.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autobroadcast threshold is limited to only 2GB (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6235) so if the table size is more than this value you will not be able to do so.
Workaround could be to provide hint to sparksql using broadcast function as follows:

```
largeTableDf.join(broadcast(smallTableDf), "key"))
```

Comment: Hi Sachin, Thank you for response. But it is still the same. I use ds1.joinWith( broadcast(ds2), ds1("key1") === ds2("key2"), "left_outer"). It is still very slow. Also, when I using untyped API or SQL, it is very fast, I don't need to use broadcast() function.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason.
In my ds1, there is also a field "key2" which is the same as join key of ds2. 
After rename ds2("key2") to ds2("key3"), and the join below is fast now.

ds1.joinWith( broadcast(ds2), ds1("key1") === ds2("key3"), "left_outer")

Can anyone please explain the reason?

Comment: I think the number of records generated when you use key2 are more than that if key1 can you post the count of number of records in both the cases